# Does a general computer port or accessory exist which can capture a custom 100 KHz digital signal?

Tags: communication

A device I need to study transmits a very clear rectangular signal, which doesn't conform to any standard communication protocol (UART, SPI, I2C, etc.) The voltage is not a problem, I can make a converter to 5 Volt or whatever is needed.

The signal has pulse lengths between ca. 10 µs and 200 µs, so an effective resolution of at least 100 KHz is expected.

Without building a custom hardware which captures the times between the pulses and transmits them via USB or whatever to a computer, do PC ports or accessories exist which can help me write a PC program which reads data from the device? I might use a digital oscilloscope and capture its output in my software, but that seems like overkill (and overly complicated).

Another possibility would be a very good sound card, but even in that case, I need pattern recognition especially if the signal is distorted, a sound card scope I tried does not provide an easily evaluable output from a 100 kHz digital signal.

Comment: Note that if the minimum pulse length is 10µs you'll probably want something above 100kHz otherwise it will be very hit and miss, I'd probably aim for 500kHz or more.

Comment: This is why I wrote effective. I'm not talking about an oscilloscope with a resolution of 100 kHz, but about a device which is suitable for signals of at least 100 kHz.

Comment: I use an [Open Bench Logic Sniffer](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Open_Bench_Logic_Sniffer) for this kind of thing.

Comment: While I see the logic and in the closing of this question, I would like to point out that I was not looking for specific products at all. The question was meant to be looking for a general answer, like what *type* of device or what *method* to use. This is why I mentioned two examples (without mentioning any products) what I was thinking of, but thought of as inefficient or overly complicated. The fun part is in "Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve" - I think this is what I just did, didn't I?

Answer (score 3):

Just about any cheap USB logic analyzer should do the trick. Examples: [Bus Pirate](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Pirate), [Saleae Logic](http://www.saleae.com/logic).

Comment: I vote for saleae logic. Great value for the price. Intuitive and very responsive.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use an MSP430 Launchpad device, which when I last bought them were $4.30 shipped to my door. They may be more, now. It already has a USB port with virtual COM port support and the MSP430 serial ports work fine with their USB chipset. I've used it to capture parallel port data using robust, precisely timed polling at 200kHz while simultaneously operating the serial port and transferring data at 9600 bps as I saw it (there is an active signal to indicate "data ready.") Could be a cheap digital scope for a custom purpose, I suppose. Daughter cards are trivial to add.

Anyway, I'd select a cheap demo board from a manufacturer where the software tools fit the purpose well (lots of choices, I'm sure) which also connects to the PC via USB and supports a virtual COM port and has whatever ram you think is suitable for a useful buffer. Just capture and download the data.

I'd expect to pay no more than $15, total. Software coding extra, of course.

Comment: Why go to all this trouble when an off-thje-shelf USB logic analyzer will do the job?

Comment: Because I'm a hobbyist and such a thing would cost me pulling down a $4.30 object from my shelf and modifying a slight bit of software to get the task done. I'm cheap and I like to have control over how things I use work. Others may have different goals.

Comment: Bus pirate is $30

Comment: Not bad. But again, that does NOT help me with "control." I understand what I write and because I understand it, I control it. Nice, though. Thanks. But even then I still prefer $4.30.